# Use the DISTINCT keyword in FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to find the distinct user IDs on comments to a post.  I know this can be done with `SQL` with the `DISTINCT` clause, but I am not sure how it might be done with `fql`.  If there is not any way, what would be one approach to doing so, assuming I pull down all the fromid on a post_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL isn't like SQL in the sense that you don't get duplicates for the same reasons SQL does (`JOIN`s, etc.), so no, there's no `DISTINCT` keyword that I know of. If you're having an issue parsing a specific query, you should post that so we can help further.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  So, could I clarify this though?  For example, if there was a post with 5 comments, but the comments were all written by 1 user.  Then a query such as this:

SELECT fromid from comment WHERE post_id = ID_OF_THE_POST

This query would return only 1 fromid in the above case?  Thank you!

Comment: No, because the duplicates are coming from the data themselves (foreign keys), not as an artifact of a join. What language are you using? If it's PHP, what I'd do is loop through your results and store each `fromid` as a key in an associative array (`$arr[$row['fromid']] = true`, for example) then get the distincts by using `array_keys($arr);`.